# Restarting WPF Application with Updater Prompt

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I've come across many post on how to restart my wpf application. From those other post, I was successfully able to restart my wpf application. The only issue is that the Click Once updater prompt that normally occurs right before the wpf application splash screen no longer appears. May I have some assistance on how to restart my application with having the updater prompt appear.

```
private void OkButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: We need more information about this. How and when do you show the prompt?

Comment: @WoIIe I should have been more detailed. It's the click once updater that occurs automatically for wpf applications upon startup

Comment: Have you tried to restart by launching as a `Process`? Remove `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();` and start a new `Process` instead invoking your application exe as argument.

Comment: In case you are mainly restarting in order to manage updates... did you consider just managing the updates instead of restarting? https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-check-for-application-updates-programmatically-using-the-clickonce-deployment-api (ofc. you would still restart after applying the update)